# Получение разметки веб страницы без участия браузера

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Для того, чтобы получить html разметку страницы и её содержимое, написал небольшое приложение на NET C#. Помогла библиотека [WatiN](http://watin.org/). Например:

```
using (var browser = new IE("http://www.адрес_страницы.ru/"))
{
   //Выполняемый код. Вызываем методы для парсинга страницы
}
```

Парсинг так можно делать, НО минус в том, что участвует браузер, т.е. дополнительное звено, которое может давать дополнительные ошибки.

Вопрос такой - есть есть ли библиотеки, инструменты, которые позволяют делать запрос к странице, веб-ресурсу без участия браузера, получать её содержимое и парсить. Отправляем запрос - получили html.

Буду очень признателен за помощь!

Comment: А как вы будете потом HTML парсить? Получить HTML можно стандартными средствами с помощью `HttpClient` (как @Bulson заметил), а дальше что?

Comment: И зачем вы добавили метки [tag:asp.net-mvc], [tag:asp.net-web-api]?

Comment: парсить HTML можно с помощью Html Agility Pack.

Comment: метки добавил, т. к. ещё не определился на основе какой технологии буду реализовывать приложение

Comment: Хорошо, а можете ответить на мой первый вопрос? И рассказать, что это будет за приложение (какую задачу будет решать), может я вам ещё что-то подскажу.

Comment: мм, извините, но вроде ответил на все Ваши вопросы. Парсить буду средствами либы Html Agility Pack, Или Вы на какой-то другой вопрос не ответил?

Comment: Приложение будет собирать инфу со страниц сайта. Т.е. пробую сделать граббер)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51041/discussion-between--and-vadim-ovchinnikov).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
static async void DownloadPageAsync()
{
    // целевой сайт
    string page = "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/";

    // используем HttpClient
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                // читаем содержимое как текст
                string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // делаем что-то полезное
                if (result != null)
                {

                }
            }
}
```

Есть еще [WebClient](http://metanit.com/sharp/net/2.1.php), но уже считается как бы слегка устаревшим что-ли, ну в общем `HttpClient` вам в руку.

Comment: Bulson, благодарю!